Spinner con Autocompletado de JQuery, se baja infinitamente
Tengo un problema con mi código, por problemas de compatibilidad entre mi JQuery 3.0 y mi Bootstrap.
Cambié la versión de JQuery a la versión 2.2.4 (Porque habían algunas funcionalidades de mi HTML no funcionaban como "dropbuttom" y otras por incompatibilidad con el Bootstrap) pero al cambiar esta versión (se arreglaron las funcionalidades que antes no servían).
No se si existe incompatibilidad entre mi jQuery y jQuery UI o es un problema de mi código, pero se alteró mi Spinner para una función de auto completado. Ahora el Spinner con la lista al invocarlo, se baja infinitamente dentro de la página, y la pagina aumenta su "height" incluso antes de invocar al Spinner.
Dejo una parte de mi HTML por si alguno sabe como puedo solucionarlo, gracias.
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" EnableEventValidation="false" MasterPageFile="~/production/MasterPage.master" CodeBehind="cotizador.aspx.vb" Inherits="cotizador" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    
    
        <!-- Bootstrap JS y Popper.js -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


        //Script
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var clientes = [];
    
            $('#<%= DropDownListClientes.ClientID %> option').each(function () {
            clientes.push({ label: $(this).text(), value: $(this).val() });
        });;;
    
        $("#clienteInput").autocomplete({
            source: clientes,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#clienteId').val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
        $("#clienteInput").on("keydown", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 9) {
                e.preventDefault();
    
                $("#spinner").show();
    
                obtenerDatosCliente(this).finally(function () {
                 
                    $("#spinner").hide();
                    $("#direccion").focus();
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>


Hola Santiago, proba indicando el appendTo, por ejemplo, appendTo: $("#clienteInput").parent()

Hola @Marcos gracias, eso solucionó que el Spinner se baje, aunque sigo con el problema que la página se expande verticalmente infinitamente

Sin poder reproducirlo, es imposible saber que genera el scroll. Puedo suponer que es un elemento en position: absolute que esta por debajo del borde inferior del viewport (tiene un bottom negativo o un top demasiado grande)

Correcto, modificando los estilos del contenedor y cuerpo de la página se solucionó, incluso no es necesario el appendTo: $("#clienteInput").parent(), se con eso, se solucionó el problema. gracias.

@SantiagoHerrera pon lo que ha respondido a tu pregunta como respuesta en base a [answer], y acéptala cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.
